# Why can't I open a text file with this code?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code to open a file entered by the user and to display the file.

However, no matter how many times I read over my book I can't seem to 
tell why my file is still not opening. I even copied someone else's code 
that worked and mine still won't open. Someone please help me I've tried 
everything.

Here is part of my code, the void function works perfectly fine and so 
does the input validation, but when I open the file nothing is displayed

```
void readFile(int list[], int size)
{
//Identify variables
ifstream inFile;
string fileName;

    cout<<"Please enter filename: ";
    cin>>fileName;

    inFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    while(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid file name. ";
        inFile.clear();
        inFile.ignore(200,'\n');
        cout<<"Please enter filename: ";
        cin>>fileName;
        inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    }
```

For some reason everything else seems to work fine but the file will not display anything when it is opened, instead the program closes.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange: this code works fine for me.

```c
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    // Identify variables
    ifstream inFile;
    string fileName, str;

    cout << "Please enter filename: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    inFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    while(!inFile) {
        cout << "Invalid file name. ";
        inFile.clear();
        inFile.ignore(200,'\n');
        cout << "Please enter filename: ";
        cin >> fileName;
        inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    }

    while (std::getline(inFile, str)) {
        cout << str;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is probably with what you do with `inFile` after opening it.

Comment: So you're saying that when you run this, the file opens? Just any text file that you named can open?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, as long as the file exists. Otherwise, it does as expected, asking again for a file name.

Comment: Oh I added getline and it worked finally thank you so much!